# OpenCV Assertion Failed Error - Perspective Transform

Tags: java, opencv, feature-detection, android

I am using OpenCV for Android Version 3.1.0. I tried to use AKAZE detector and AKAZE descriptor. When I run the code on my Emulator am getting the below error.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn + 1 == m.cols) in void CV:perspectiveTransform(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray), 
file/Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 2125

core::perspectiveTransform_10() caught cv::Exception: /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:2125: 
error: (-215) scn + 1 == m.cols in function void CV:perspectiveTransform(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray)
```

I am using

```
private final Mat firstCorners = new Mat(4,1, CvType.CV_32FC2)

private final Mat secondCorners = new Mat(4,1, CvType.CV_32FC2)

final Mat homography = Calib3d.findHomography(first, second, Calib3d.RANSAC, 1)

Core.perspectiveTransform(firstCorners, secondCorners, homography)
```

I tried new Mat(4,1, CvType.CV_32FC1) but of no use

any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and was able to fix it by using `MatOfPoint2f` - here is the code in Kotlin:

```
val dstPtsCoords = MatOfPoint2f()
val srcPtsCoords = MatOfPoint2f()
dstPtsCoords.fromList(dstPointArray) // Array from matches
srcPtsCoords.fromList(srcPointArray) // Array from matches

val H = Calib3d.findHomography(srcPtsCoords, dstPtsCoords, Calib3d.RANSAC, 1)

val undistortedReferencePoints = MatOfPoint2f()
undistortedReferencePoints.fromArray(
    Point(0.0, 0.0),
    Point(reference_width - 1.0, 0.0),
    Point(reference_width - 1.0, reference_height - 1.0),
    Point(0.0, reference_height - 1.0)
)
val dstPoints = MatOfPoint2f() // top left, bottom left, bottom right, top right
perspectiveTransform(undistortedReferencePoints, dstPoints, H)
```